# LWC Dynamic Flow Modal without Aura

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, modal

Is it possible to make a simple LWC (without aura) that loads a dynamic Flow (text parameter) into a modal popup? I would think this would have already existed using the [SLDS Modal](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/messaging/components/modals/) but every sample I come across seems much more complicated than necessary; with dependencies on other code repos/components ([for example](https://github.com/tsalb/lwc-utils/blob/c923201535ccd90780ae8f43b6757afe189e7563/force-app/main/default/lwc/flowWizardLauncherExample/flowWizardLauncherExample.js)). Unfortunately my JS is not very strong so I'm having trouble getting this concept to work.

I've found this [simple example](https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/01/popupmodal-box-in-salesforce-lightning.html) for setting up a modal but I don't understand how I would dynamically load a Flow into it. Can anyone provide some insight or explanation?

Comment: Also encountering this need. Checked your '(for example)' and looks like it's communicating with Aura component to achieve it.  

worth voting on following unless someone finds a LWC only method:  

Embed FLow in LWC
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdaxrUAB/embed-flow-in-lwc

Answer (score 0):

Create a lwc component with modal html in it and create an `@api` variable in the js. Bind the value of `@api` variable to the html. Pass the value from parent component to show in the modal.